# Equivalent to Perl's END block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a Perl equivalent END block in Ruby? In Perl, if I specify an END block, the code in that block will get executed no matter where the program bails out. It is great functionality for closing open file handles. Does Ruby support similar functionality? I tried Ruby's "END{}" block but that doesnt seem to get called if I had an exit in the code due to an error.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using [`exit!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21) to exit, rather than [`exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exit)? For `exit!`: "No exit handlers are run." which seems to apply to both `END` blocks and `at_exit` handlers.

Comment: Consider using `IO.open`/`new` with blocks, so you don't have to close the files yourself.

Comment: Documentation link for `END`: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-END . I've never seen it used in actual code, whereas I have seen `Kernel#at_exit` used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`at_exit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit), which will run regardless of whether an exception was raised or not:

```
at_exit { puts 'exited!' }
raise
```

prints "exited" as expected.

You should only consider this if you cannot use an `ensure`, as `at_exit` causes logic to reside far away from where the actual exit occurs.

Comment: Thank you. at_exit worked. Unlike Perl, I had to add `at_exit` before the first exit was called.

Comment: Yes, if you exit *before* calling `at_exit`, then `at_exit` of course never got called and thus the hook not added. `at_exit` happens at runtime, not parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A block may have an 'ensure' clause. Here's an example:

```
begin
  # This will cause a divide by zero exception
  puts 3 / 0
rescue Exception => e
  puts "An error occurred: #{e}"
ensure
  puts "I get run anyway"
end
```

Running this produces:

```
An error occurred: divided by 0
I get run anyway
```